# Laravel - consulta middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, blade, laravel-6

tengo una duda de planteamiento.
Tengo un proyecto con Laravel y he instalado socialite porque quiero conectar mediante oauth2 con Outlook 365, este paso lo tengo hecho y funcionando.
Me logueo con una cuenta del dominio autorizado y acceso a las páginas que tengo definidas en el proyecto laravel si tengo token o no.

Para ello uso un código como este

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use function Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function profile()
    {
        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
        }

        $tokenCache = new \App\TokenStore\TokenCache;
        $accesToken = $tokenCache->getAccessToken();

        if (null === $accesToken || '' === $accesToken) {
            return redirect()->route('signin');
        }

        return \view('profile')->with('token', $accesToken);
    }
}
```

Profile() es un método que me devuelve una vista si el usuario tiene token y sinó me redirige a una ruta que es signin.

Mi pregunta es si esto deberia ir dentro de un middleware y comprobar si el usuario esta loggeado dejar acceso y sinó redireccionar a la ruta signin.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor es que lo coloques dentro del Middleware, los middlewares funcionan como un filtro de las peticiones, esto te sera útil, ya que quieres que el usuario tenga acceso a tu aplicación y los Middleware se ejecutan antes que el controlador, en tu archivo de rutas lo puedes colocar así:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['tuMiddleware']], function () {
    //Rutas a las que permitir el acceso
});
```